# Wordpress - template part break wordpress columns layout

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I think that some help will be appreciated. I have this code that will load two template part for a wordpres custom theme:

```
    <div class="row m-0">
        <?php get_template_part('assets/main', 'news'); ?>
        <?php get_template_part('assets/side', 'news'); ?>
    </div>
```

As you can see under the hood I'm using bootstrap 4 so it's supposed that the content will align itself inside the same row.

I have a `col-8` inside the `main-news.php` and a `col-4` inside the `side-news.php` so I supposed that I will have the contents aligned, but this will not happen and my layout will break.

this is the code inside the `main.news.php` teplate part:

```
<?php $main_news = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'category_name' => 'main-news', 'posts_per_page' => 4) ); ?>
        <!-- main -->
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8 mt-2">
            <p class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold mb-0 section-title"><?php _e('Last news') ?></p>
        </div>
        <?php if( $main_news->have_posts() ): while( $main_news->have_posts() ): $main_news->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8 mt-2 mb-2">
            <div class="card rounded-0 p-0">
                <img class="card-img-top w-100 h-100 rounded-0" src="<?php echo the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" />
                <div class="card-img-overlay news-overlay">
                    <a class="h4 stretched-link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata() ?>
```

this is the content of `side-news.php`

```
<?php $middle_news = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'post', 'category_name' => 'market-news', 'posts_per_page' => 4 ) ); ?>
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <p class="text-uppercase font-weight-bold mb-0 section-title"><?php _e('Side news') ?></p>
</div>
<?php if( $middle_news->have_posts() ): while( $middle_news->have_posts() ): $middle_news->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4 mt-2 mb-2">
        <img class="img-fluid w-100" src="<?php echo the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" />
        <a class="h4 stretched-link" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>        
    </div>
<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

How I can fix the layout to have the col-8 and the col-4 on the same row line?Maybe I need to nest the loops or what?
See the scree to understand what's happening now

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your mistake is inside the `main-news.php` file.
look, you defined these `(col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8 )` for your first div tag in the `main-news.php` file so your div takes those columns and then you defined these `(col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8 )` columns for the div tag inside of the `loop` at the same file so both `divs` take more than 12 columns just inside the `main-news.php` file whereas you defined `(col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4)` for the div inside of the `side-news.php` file again so these definitions break your code.

Solution: You should `delete` the columns definition from one of the `divs` inside the `main-news.php` file.

GOOD LUCK!!!